# Getting value with htaccess and pagination for limit

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

This url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category
```

would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category
```

Also, there is pagination and limit url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category&p=2&limit=20
```

and it would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category?page=2&limit=20
```

this url also work

```
example.com/videos/video-category?page=2

example.com/videos/video-category?limit=20
```

Here is my htaccess (into `videos` folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([1-9][0-9]*)$ load.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

how to do this.. plz help me.. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+videos/load\.php\?cat=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That satisfies the question you're asking, but your rules have stuff for `/page/`, which isn't part of your question at all.

Comment: plz if you can help me for this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381679/htaccess-change-a-path-to-a-query-strings