# .htaccess change a path to a query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pagination

I have files in example.com/

```
contact.php
recent.php
videos.php
watch.php
```

`example.com/page/` > `/page/` is not a folder. but i want to work other folders

contact.php (no pagination)

```
example.com/page/contact
```

recent.php (`pagination > recent.php?page=2`)

```
example.com/page/recent
example.com/page/recent?page=2
```

watch.php (`no pagination > watch.php?title=drama-name`)

```
example.com/page/watch/drama-name
```

videos.php (`pagination with get name > videos.php?name=drama-name&page=2`)

```
example.com/page/videos/drama-name
example.com/page/videos/drama-name?page=2
```

Here is my full htaccess codes (example.com/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^page/playlist$ /playlist.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/submit$ /submit.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/contact$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/search$ /search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/recent$ /recent.php [L]

RewriteRule ^page/watch/([^/]+)? /watch.php?title=$1

RewriteRule ^page/videos/([^/]+)? /videos.php?name=$1
```

But not work in `/page/videos/drama-name?page=2` how to fix it? it has another problem?

Comment: You need to add `QSA` flag with `L` flag in order to append the query string to the rewritten file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine regex and shorten your rules in your .htaccess with `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add www in host name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page/(submit|contact|search|recent|playlist)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/(videos|watch)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: but now in all pages work this one `/page/contact/` i want it like this `/page/contact` only.. note: is it good for seo or not?

Comment: ohhh it has another problem also. in last RewriteRule only take watch.php but i have another file like videos.php how to give it